# Relation between condition numbers $\kappa(A^T A)$ and $\kappa(A)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a real $m\times n$ matrix. Why is the [condition number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number) $\kappa(A^T A)$ approximately the square of the $\kappa(A)$?

Answer (score 4):

The easiest answer is to assume we're talking about the 2-norm condition number and use the SVD. The condition number is $\sigma_1/\sigma_r$, where $r$ is the rank (assuming $A$ is full rank, otherwise this whole discussion makes no sense). Write $A=U \Sigma V^T$, then

$$A^T A = V \Sigma^T U^T U \Sigma V^T = V \Sigma^T \Sigma V^T.$$

The result is an SVD of $A^T A$, where the singular value matrix is $\Sigma^T \Sigma$. So the singular values of $A^T A$ are the squares of the singular values of $A$. Thus the largest one gets squared and the smallest one gets squared, so the ratio gets squared. Thus in the 2-norm the condition number is *exactly* squared by this procedure. Equivalence of norms in finite dimensional spaces means that the same is "approximately" true in other norms as well.

The only particularly nontrivial facts here are that the SVD exists and that the 2-norm of a matrix is its largest singular value.